# Get the tags of selected text in JTextPane

Tags: java, html, tags, jtextpane

Good morning dear all,
I have a JTextPane with the content type 'text/html'. In this JTextPane I load Bible where versets are separated by tag. What I want to do is to determine the selected verset when a user click on a part of the document.
From now, I'm able to get the selected text with the method getSelectedText(). But the result does not contains the tags of the original document which can help me detect the beginning or ending of the verset in which the selected text is contains.

I cannot make a simple search, because, the method getSelectedText() return a text without tag. For example the result of the

```
Abraham eut pour descendant <g v=\"Isaac\">Isaac</g>.
```

will be "Abraham eut pour descendant Isaac."
So, if I make simple search I will find nothing.
In summary, what I want is to know how to get the tag of the selected text so that I can determine the verset of the selected text.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class VersetBibliques {

    Rectangle[] rects = new Rectangle[2];
    HTMLEditorKit kit;
    HTMLDocument htmlDoc;    

    private JPanel getContent() {
        rects[0] = new Rectangle();
        rects[1] = new Rectangle();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 10, 0));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(getTextPane()));
        return panel;
    }

    private JTextPane getTextPane() {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        htmlDoc = new HTMLDocument();
        textPane.setEditable(false);

        textPane.setEditorKit(kit);
        textPane.setDocument(htmlDoc);
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        textPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        textPane.setFont(new Font("Arial Bold", Font.ITALIC, 38));
        try {
            kit.insertHTML(htmlDoc, 0, text, 0, 0, null);                
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            System.out.println("bad location: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        textPane.addMouseListener(selector);
        Style s = htmlDoc.addStyle("logical", null);
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(s, "georgia");
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(s, 58);
        s = htmlDoc.addStyle("lineSpace", null);
        StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(s, 0.25f);
        htmlDoc.setLogicalStyle(0, htmlDoc.getStyle("logical"));
        return textPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VersetBibliques test = new VersetBibliques();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(test.getContent());
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private MouseListener selector = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                JTextPane textPane = (JTextPane) e.getComponent();
                int start = textPane.getSelectionStart() - 10;
                int end = textPane.getSelectionEnd() + 10;

                textPane.setSelectionEnd(end);
                textPane.setSelectionStart(start);

                String selectedText = textPane.getSelectedText();
                System.out.println("text content : " + selectedText);//Il faudra faire le test avec Jean 11:35
                System.out.println("start: "+start+"- end:"+end);


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    String text = "<mt>Évangile selon Matthieu</mt>\n"
            + "<c><cn>1</cn>\n"
            + "<mt>Naissance et enfance de Jésus</mt><s>La généalogie de Jésus</s><r>(<ref v=\"LUK3.23-38\">Lc 3.23-38</ref>)</r><v><vn>1</vn>Voici la généalogie de Jésus-Christ, de la descendance de <g v=\"David\">David</g> et d'<g v=\"Abraham\">Abraham</g>. </v>"
            + "<p/><v><q><vn>2 </vn>Abraham eut pour descendant <g v=\"Isaac\">Isaac</g>.<br/>Isaac eut pour descendant <g v=\"Jacob\">Jacob</g>.<br/>Jacob eut pour descendant <g v=\"Juda\">Juda</g> et ses frères.</q></v>"
            + "<v><q><vn>3 </vn>De Thamar, Juda eut pour descendant Péretz et Zérah.<br/>Péretz eut pour descendant Hetsrom.<br/>Hetsrom eut pour descendant Aram.</q></v>"
            + "<v><q><vn>4 </vn>Aram eut pour descendant Aminadab.<br/>Aminadab eut pour descendant Nahchôn,<br/>Nahchôn eut pour descendant Salma.</q></v>"
            + "<v><q><vn>5 </vn>De Rahab, Salma eut pour descendant Booz.<br/>De Ruth, Booz eut pour descendant Obed.</q></v></c>";

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read html from the document, you need to use [HTMLEditorKit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html). Especially the `write` method.

To get the selection offset, you need to use `getSelectionStart` and `getSelectionEnd`, or just `getCaretPosition`, from [JTextPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html)

To get the markup around these offsets, you can use `getCharacterElement().getStartOffset()` and `getCharacterElement().getEndOffset()` from [HTMLDocument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html).

Finally, here is a sample to show you how to use these:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String text = "<p><mt>Évangile selon Matthieu</mt>\n"
                        + "<c><cn>1</cn>\n"
                        + "<mt>Naissance et enfance de Jésus</mt><s>La généalogie de Jésus</s><r>(<ref v=\"LUK3.23-38\">Lc 3.23-38</ref>)</r><v><vn>1</vn>Voici la généalogie de Jésus-Christ, de la descendance de <g v=\"David\">David</g> et d'<g v=\"Abraham\">Abraham</g>. </v>"
                        + "<p/><v><q><vn>2 </vn>Abraham eut pour descendant <g v=\"Isaac\">Isaac</g>.<br/>Isaac eut pour descendant <g v=\"Jacob\">Jacob</g>.<br/>Jacob eut pour descendant <g v=\"Juda\">Juda</g> et ses frères.</q></v>"
                        + "<v><q><vn>3 </vn>De Thamar, Juda eut pour descendant Péretz et Zérah.<br/>Péretz eut pour descendant Hetsrom.<br/>Hetsrom eut pour descendant Aram.</q></v>"
                        + "<v><q><vn>4 </vn>Aram eut pour descendant Aminadab.<br/>Aminadab eut pour descendant Nahchôn,<br/>Nahchôn eut pour descendant Salma.</q></v>"
                        + "<v><q><vn>5 </vn>De Rahab, Salma eut pour descendant Booz.<br/>De Ruth, Booz eut pour descendant Obed.</q></v></c></p>";

                final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("test");
                mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                final JTextPane field = new JTextPane();
                field.setContentType("text/html");

                HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit) field.getEditorKit();
                HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) field.getDocument();

                try (StringReader r = new StringReader(text)) {
                    kit.read(r, field.getDocument(), 0);
                } catch (IOException | BadLocationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                field.setCaretPosition(10);
                field.setSelectionStart(doc.getCharacterElement(field.getCaretPosition()).getParentElement().getStartOffset());
                field.setSelectionEnd(doc.getCharacterElement(field.getCaretPosition()).getParentElement().getEndOffset());

                try (StringWriter w = new StringWriter()) {
                    kit.write(w, field.getDocument(), field.getSelectionStart(), field.getSelectionEnd()-field.getSelectionStart());
                    System.out.println(w.toString());
                } catch (IOException | BadLocationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                mainFrame.getContentPane().add(field,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                mainFrame.setSize(500,500);
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then, you still have some issues to fix, like the fact that non-html markup won't be correctly represented by the JTextPane, so you have to fix the ViewFactory to create your own XMLViewFactory, but this is another subject.

Comment: Thank a lot. It is exactly what I want. And about the usage of my own markup, could you give me a good link about ViewFactory and XMLVievFactory management.

Comment: Once your problem is solved, please select an answer. This is important for this place to work. ;)

Comment: I'm agree with you and I just do the same.

Comment: Use the tick mark on the left of the answer to select this answer and mark your problem as solved.

Comment: @Doukya If you are new to Stackoverflow, please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)